# Substring question with trailing characters

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm using a substring function to get specific substrings I need from a longer string (duh).

Lets say my string is: "*(....) partijen waarvan de **lower quartile 0,68**% bedraagt en de **upper quartile 2,06**%*."

The bold values is what I'm after. Now, the following two functions work perfectly:

```
content_higher = content_conclusion[content_conclusion.index("upper quartile"):content_conclusion.index("%.")]
content_lower = content_conclusion[content_conclusion.index("lower quartile"):content_conclusion.index("%")]
```

As you can see, for the "upper quartile" (this is tranfer pricing / tax related) the % character is followed by a dot (.) because the string ends here.

When I would change the function to find that upper quartile value to the below, the function no longer works:

```
content_higher = content_conclusion[content_conclusion.index("upper quartile"):content_conclusion.index("%")] #i.e., without the dot (.) that follows the % character
```

I understand that this is probably because this % sign is always directly (i.e., without space) followed by a dot (.). However, is it possible to ignore such following characters.
I would like to be able to search for specific characters/substrings regardless of what follows this substring directly after.

In other words, can I substring on specific characters with wildcards.

Hope the above is clear. Many thanks for your input!

Comment: `content_conclusion.index("%")` is going to find the *first* percent sign in the string - which in this case is the one after "lower quartile", not the one you want.  `str.index()` does take an optional second parameter that specifies where to begin searching - if you passed the result of `content_conclusion.index("upper quartile")` here, the proper matching % would be found.

Comment: @jasonharper Dude thank you. I'm retarded. For future reference (perhaps other users): the problem was not the trailing dot (.) after the % character, but the fact that it was looking for the first occurence of the % character (which was in in front of the first index of the substring function - thus resulting in no output).

The fix (as you perfectly mentioned) is as follows (confirmed that it works):

content_higher = content_conclusion[content_conclusion.index("upper quartile"):content_conclusion.index("%", content_conclusion.index("upper quartile"))]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python Regular Expressions to achieve this.

Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

I came up with the below solution.

```py
import re

txt = "partijen waarvan de lower quartile 0,68% bedraagt en de upper quartile 2,06%."
x = re.findall("lower quartile \d,\d\d%", txt)
y = re.findall("upper quartile \d,\d\d%", txt)

print(f'Lower Quartile: {x[0][-5:]}')
print(f'Upper Quartile: {y[0][-5:]}')

### Output
# Lower Quartile: 0,68%
# Upper Quartile: 2,06%
```

Comment: That's a poor usage of `re`. There are ways, for example, to get all values in just one call of `re.findall`. It would be better to first understand them before proposing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a pattern ending with a word boundary after matching the digits.

```
\b(?:lower|upper) quartile \d+(?:,\d+)?\b
```

- `b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?:lower|upper) quartile`  Match one of the alternatives, then `quartile`
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4JHKe/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YITWAq)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\b(?:lower|upper) quartile \d+(?:,\d+)?\b"
s = "(....) partijen waarvan de lower quartile 0,68% bedraagt en de upper quartile 2,06%."
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['lower quartile 0,68', 'upper quartile 2,06']
```